# To get the total length of overlapped intervals using Segment tree with lazy propogation

Tags: algorithm

So here's the problem: given a set of intervals [a,b) where a,b is integers,0<=a < b=10^5, what's the length of all the interval(overlapped parts will only be counted once)? if we want to support two operations: add(a,b), and remove(a,b) ([a,b) exist in the set in the case of remove), which add and remove interval [a,b) to and from the set then return the new total length, can you do them in O(logn), where n is 10^5? .eg: if we have interval [1,3),[2,4), then the total length is 3 in this case.

My approach to it is using Segment tree, nodes of which is

```
class Segnode:
    def __init__(self,start,end):
        self.start,self.end = start,end
        self.left,self.right = None,None
        self.layer,self.cover = 0,0
        self.lazy = 0
```

where layer record how many intervals cover this node (eg: if we have a set of [0,3),[1,3),[1,2), then the `Segnode(1,3)` will have layer 2, because only [0,3) and [1,3) totally cover it); cover record the length of the part of this node that covered(eg: `Segnode(1,3)` in last example will have cover 2).

But the thing is I couldn't come up with a correct,LAZY way to update the tree (if we don't use lazy propagation then the problem is trivial, but time complexity could reach O(n) where n could be 10^5 per operation). Can someone help me with this part? is there a correct, lazy approach to this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lazy-propagation-in-segment-tree/

Comment: @juvian, thank you. I know how to do lazy propagation in general, but I don't know how to do it in this case.

Comment: Are the removes always an interval which was added before?

Comment: @juvian, yes, the removed interval already exsit

Comment: post your code?  also edit to add correct language

Comment: Is this an online site problem? Do you have original problem statement?